# Sublime Text folder_exclude_patterns stopped working

Tags: sublimetext2

I have this in my `myapp.sublime-project` file in the root of my project.

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
      "path": ".",
      "folder_exclude_patterns": ["log", "tmp"],
      "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.sublime-workspace"]
        }
    ],
  "settings":
  {
    "tab_size": 2
  }
}
```

Previously this was working (for example log/development.log would be exluded in search results).  But somehow it stopped working a week or two ago and I can't figure out why.

Any ideas on how to debug this is or is this syntax still correct in the latest sublime?  Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

If you open your project with `subl .` from command line as I often do:

```
# project_folder> subl .
```

These settings are getting ignored. As a workaround I use Project menu and use one of `Open Recent` or `Quick Switch Project`. Then, settings in `sublime-project` file are getting applied. Yes, weird indeed.

I've asked about this to the forum: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14129

Comment: Didn't know that the sublime project had to be opened specifically. Wrote up a short script to work around this. https://gist.github.com/imjared/7010577

Comment: i have 2221 build. I had the same problem. I open project by "subl .", and then project settings about file_exclue_patterns not work. This answer is correct and helped me.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do both, simultaneously, of @Chengjian and @Case's answers:

1. Close the project.
2. delete the .sublime-workspace file.
3. Reopen.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have appname.sublime-workspace hence my appname.sublime-project was not working.

Opened the folder and tried project save as 
"Project: Save As"

It created 2 files

- appname.sublime-project
- appname.sublime-workspace

After that the folder_exclude_patterns settings started to work fine.

Thanks -> https://coderwall.com/p/znswpq

Answer (score 3):

For me the following "solution" worked in Sublimetext **3**:

1. Save and close all open files in Sublimetext
2. Go to `Project > Open Project...`
3. Select your `project.sublime-project` in the project folder

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: yes this helped! If you want to add the hidden .git folder: `{"folders":[{"path":".git"},{"path":"."}]}`

Answer (score 2):

I copied your project file verbatim into a barebones project folder:

```
myapp
    log
        development.log
    Valid logfile.log
    myapp.sublime-project
    myapp.sublime-workspace
```

And as expected, `development.log` was excluded from my Goto Anything results, while `Valid log file.log` was included. As far as I can tell, your syntax is correct as of Sublime Text 2 2.0.1, Build 2217.

Make sure the project is open by checking the titlebar: `filename — myapp` means that the project `myapp` is open. You can also try explicitly removing files in `log` from your search results by adding `"log/*"` to `file_exclude_patterns`. This should guarantee that no files in the log folder are included in your project.

Comment: Interesting, I also have 2.0.1 Build 2217.  Not sure why the change :/  Maybe a plugin I installed or something.

Comment: That could be it. My plugins: AdvancedNewFile, Alignment, Auto Semi-Colon, CoffeeScript, Package Control, PyV8, and QuickFileMove.

Comment: I'm also and running into this problem on build 2217 on a mac. I'd list all the packages I have installed, but I have a ton and there is no easy way (I've found) to export a list.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat relevant: I added `"folder_exclude_patterns": ["bower_components"]` to my global user preferences file, but it didn't immediately start working in my active project. It started working though, after closing then re-opening the project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `*.sublime-workspace` file in order to let the new setting take affect.

Answer (score 0):

As SelimOber has already stated, trying to open a project with `subl .` wont look at `*.sublime-project` settings, hence `folder_exclude_patterns` wont work.

You can simply create an alias to solve that. Add `alias lime='subl *.sublime-project'` to your `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc` if you're using zsh).

You can then run `lime` to open Sublime in current path along with the settings in `.sublime-project` file. Of course, `lime` can be whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this works for me, but try to rename your file

```
myapp.sublime-project -> .myapp.sublime-project
```

just add dot before name. Close and then open Project->Open Project

Answer (score 0):

Check section: `"project": "",` in `.sublime-workspace` file.
That's probably broken.

You have two options how to fix this, depending on which information you don't want to loose.

- If you don't want to loose information in `.sublime-project` file

You must fix/remove the `"project": ""` section in `.sublime-workspace` file.
Search for `"project": "` It can't be empty. There should be a name of associated `.sublime-project` file.

- If you don't want to loose actual folder list visible in Sublime, but don't care about deleting `.sublime-project` file

Go to Sublime Text by opening `.sublime-workspace` and do Project > Save Project As...
Rewrite the `.sublime-project` file (this step will fix that section in `.sublime-workspace` file)

---

If the `"project": "",` value is empty or wrong, `.sublime-project` file is ignored and sections `folders`, `build_systems`, `settings` which are normally read from `.sublime-project` file are created and used from `.sublime-workspace` file.

Removing bad `"project": "",` section from `.sublime-workspace` file works if there is `.sublime-project` file with the same name in the same folder. Sublime will recreate correct project section on next start of instance using it.

Notes: `.sublime-workspace` file can't be updated in Sublime instance which is using it, changes will be ignored. This is different to `.sublime-project` file, which can and should be edited in the same instance.

`folders` section will on next run dissapear from `.sublime-workspace` file

This situation should not normally happen.
In my case, I did save Workplace of a project, then a script created an empty `.sublime-project` file before next run.
It will probably also happen if you rename these files externally.